# Finding word in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an sorted array e.g

```
var arr = [ "aasd","march","mazz" ,"xav" ];
```

And i want to find the first occurance of letter that starts with "m" here it would be 1 . Is thee any way how to do it without looping trought whole array?

Comment: Do you mean looping using `for`, `while`? What about `map`, `forEach`, `filter`?

Comment: Why don't you want to loop through the array? Any way you do this will have to loop through at least part of the array.

Comment: `arr.find(s => s[0]==="m")`

Comment: Or if you wanted the index: `arr.findIndex(s => s[0]==="m")`

Comment: Without looping, as of my knowledge, you cannot do it.. But with looping **[`here is the solution`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/64fg2Lt2/)**

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way how to do it without looping trought whole array?

Yes, loop until you've found the match.

If you want to avoid a `for` or `while` construct, you can use `Array`'s [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find) method.

For example, `arr.find(word => word.startsWith("m"))` should return the result you expect (or undefined if there's no such word).

Answer (score 5):

You could use a binary search to find any word starting with that letter, then loop backwards until you get the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to search for the first match that meets your constraint.

The [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) function could easily handle this :

```
// Your array
var arr = [ "aasd","march","mazz" ,"xav" ];
// This will find the first match that starts with "m"
arr.find(function(word){ return word.startsWith('m');}); // yields "march"
```

Or if you needed a bit more extensive pattern matching, you could use a regular expression via the [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function, which can be seen in the following example and handles the same scenario (matching a string that begins with "m") :

```
// Your array
var arr = [ "aasd","march","mazz" ,"xav" ];
// First match that starts with "m" 
var match = arr.find(function(word){ return /^m/i.test(word);}); // yields "march"
```

**Example**

```js
var arr = ["aasd", "march", "mazz", "xav"];
var match = arr.find(function(word) { return /^m/i.test(word); });
alert(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to loop through the *whole* array - only until such time as you find what you're interested in

```
function findFirstIndex(arr, char){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       if(arr[i].substring(0,1) === char)
           return i;
    }
    return -1; // not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
function find(letter, array) {
    var index;
    array.some(function (a, i) {
        if (a[0] === letter) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return index;
}

var arr = ["aasd", "march", "mazz", "xav"];

document.write(find('m', arr));
```